# In behave, how do you run a scenario only?

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I have a 'behave' feature that has a lot of tests on it.

I only need to run a specific scenario for development needs.

How do I do it?

(preferably on the command line)

Answer (score 47):

If you want to run a single test for that feature, use the `-n` or `--name` flag which seems to want the text after `Scenario:`

```
behave -n 'This is a scenario name'
```

---

You can run a feature file by using `-i` or `--include` flags and then the name of the feature file.

```
behave -i file_name.feature
```

or:

```
behave --include file_name
```

---

You can also exclude with the `--exclude` flag:

```
behave -e file_name
```

---

For more information check the documentation for [command line arguments](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave/#command-line-arguments). There's a lot of useful information hidden in their appendix section.

---

NOTE: At the time I'm writing this it won't work with Python 3.6 and Behave 1.2.5, due to this [issue](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/536). (UPDATE: 1.2.6 is out and fixes this, but if you're on python 3.4 that version won't be available from pip so you can  workaround this with `pip3 install git+https://github.com/behave/behave#1.2.6rc` ).

It also seems like you should be able to pass in the text after `Feature:` for the -i flag but currently that doesn't work. Somebody remind me to updated if it works again. I also encourage people to check out the wip flag, which allows you to add `@wip` to a test, then `-wip` will not only run the test but also allow print/logging statements for debugging.

Answer (score 35):

To run only a single scenario you can use `-n` with the name of the scenario:

```
$ behave -n 'clicking the button "foo" should bar the baz'
```

I'm using single quotes above to keep the name of the scenario as *one* argument for `-n`. Otherwise, the shell will pass each word of the scenario name as a separate argument.

Comment: single quotes don't seem to work in Windows command interpreter, it seems double quotes are needed in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Tags provide a couple of options ...

1) Tag the slow ones and then avoid by invoking with the inverse e.g.

```
behave -t '~@slow_tag_name'
```

2) However for the most flexibility I'd personally recommend tagging each Scenario with a unique ID. e.g. I use  a `@YYYY_MM_DD_HHmm_Initials` tag scheme since, this is unique enough and the traceability is useful/interesting. Then you can always simply invoke with the tag and get it to run the Scenario, .e.g

```
behave @2015_01_03_0936_jh
```

Answer (score 1):

A very powerful trick in `behave`:

```sh
behave --wip
```

And tag your test-under-development with `@wip` for the time being. This would have been my #1 answer besides the other mentioned ways to select tests (`--name`, `--tags`, `--include`), but is quite much hidden yet in the answer by @Cynic.

Answer (score 0):

Also you might well be interested in [this](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/377) beautiful post describing how to run just a single test from a scenario outline in behave.

e.g.

```
#This is Gherkin
Feature: Running a single test from a scenario outline

@scenarioGroupName @scenarioGroupName<scenarioName>
Scenario Outline: test running one of many scenarios, iteration <n> / <scenarioName>
  Given test is index <n> for <scenarioName> 
  When we do something with <scenarioParameter>  
  Then all the checks pass


Examples: Test scenarios
 |n | scenarioName  | scenarioParameter
 |1 | Able          | first
 |2 | Baker         | second 
 |3 | Charlie       | third
 #etc
```

To run this with just data for scenario 2/baker, one might do

```
# This is shell
behave -k --tags=@scenarioGroupNameBaker
```

Note how `scenarioGroupNameBaker` tag is built.
For each example row, the outline/template tag `scenarioGroupName<scenarioName>` has `<scenarionName>` replaced with the value from the example row to give the tag name per scenario-row :D