# How to run behave multiple features using just features names

Tags: bdd, python-behave

I'm struggling with running behave features using below command:

```
behave feature_name_1 feature_name_2
```

I would like to run a few features in one command giving only feature's name or feature's name.feature.
For now, I have to indicate the whole path where the feature is.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-i` or `--include`.

```
behave -i myfeature.feature
```

This can also be used with patterns.

Alternatively use -n to match the names of your files:

```
behave -n myfeature1.feature -n myfeature2.feature
```

From the documentation:

> n, --name
>
> Only execute the feature elements which match part  of the given name.
>   If this option is given more than once,  it will match against all the
>   given names.

More information on running particular scenarios, etc. can be found in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27030233/363592); documentation [here](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html#command-line-arguments).

Comment: behave -i or even with --include still doesn't work. ConfigError: No steps directory is displayed

Comment: Please include a bit more info in the question. What have you tried that works? What's the difference between that, and what doesn't work? What happens if you use the `--verbose` arg?

Comment: Does it work with just one feature? If so please try what @manzanero proposed - use -i between each feature name.

Comment: yes, it works just for one feature. When I use -i between each feature name it will run only second feature. On example: `behave -i myfeature.feature -i myfeature2.feature` - only myfeature2.feature will be launched

Comment: So I've taken the 2nd one out of my answer; thanks for letting me know. Have you tried using glob or regex patterns with -i? I don't have a copy of the software to hand to try it out. What happens when you try it with two and you use --verbose? Please also try -n with multiple feature names `-n featureone.feature -n feature2.feature` as that matches names rather than patterns.